# Changing content of a Frame

Tags: java, swing

I am making a GUI for a Java application. What I am trying to do is have a frame, and based on user actions change the panel being displayed. Although if I do something like this :

```
private void setFrameContent(Container content) {
        appFrame.setContentPane(content);
    }
```

the frame will just freeze once I try to change the `JPanel` being displayed. Also tried some variations on this.

> How should I change the content of the frame?

One option would be CardLayout but that would mean I would have to create all the panels on app startup while some of them might not be used. What other ways are there to achieve this?

Comment: *"One option would be CardLayout but that would mean I would have to create all the panels on app startup"*  I wouldn't have to.  You must be doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes I realised later i could add panels on runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) if you add `JComponent` to the already visible Container, then you have to call for `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, in your case

- for Java7 is there implemeted `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to `JFrame` directly
- for Jav6 and lower version you have to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for `ContentPane`

2) I think that [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) (still) could be better options for switching betweens `Views` in Swing GUI

Comment: Just thought to add content on the CardLayout during runtime and then display it. Guess that should work

Comment: CardLayout is about Views added to the JFrame, not about changing or swapping betweens two or more CardLayout in one JFrame on runtime